# template declaration of `typedef typename Foo<T>::Bar Bar'

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename

I am encountering great difficulty in declaring a templated type as shown below.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
class Foo
{
 typedef T Bar;
};

template <class T>
typedef typename Foo<T>::Bar Bar;




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Bar bar;

    Foo<int> foo;


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get error

```
template declaration of `typedef typename Foo<T>::Bar Bar'
```

about line

```
template <class T>
typedef typename Foo<T>::Bar Bar;
```

I am doing this because I want avoid writing typename Foo::Bar throught my code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `typedef` declaration in C++ cannot be a template. However, C++11 added an alternative syntax using the `using` declaration to allow parametrized type aliases:

```
template <typename T>
using Bar = typename Foo<T>::Bar;
```

Now you can use:

```
Bar<int> x;   // is a Foo<int>::Bar
```

Comment: Thank you! all of you have been equally helpful. I wish I could accept all three answer received. Anyway I will vote up all three answer.

Comment: @geraldCelente: I don't think it matters or anyone would be upset -- pick whichever answer you find most useful :-) (Or toss a coin.)

Comment: is there a library (eg: boost) that provides a "backaround" for compilers that are still falling off the C++11 bandwagon (like the gcc/mingw compilers)?

Answer (score 9):

`typedef`'s cannot be templates. This is exactly the reason C++11 invented alias templates. Try

```
template <class T>
using Bar = typename Foo<T>::Bar;
```

Comment: Thank you! all of you have been equally helpful. I wish I could accept all three answer received. Anyway I will vote up all three answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can't `typedef` a template. However, you can use an alias template. The code below demonstrates the use and fixed a few other problems, too:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef T Bar;
};

template <class T>
using Bar =  typename Foo<T>::Bar;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Bar<int> bar;
    Foo<int> foo;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! all of you have been equally helpful. I wish I could accept all three answer received. Anyway I will vote up all three answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it's okay to add late answers...

I'm still using VS2012 which does not appear to implement alias templates, so I resorted to this concoction for my purposes:

```
//map<CWinThread*, AKTHREADINFO<T> > mapThreads;   // won't compile
#define MAP_THREADS(T) map<CWinThread*, AKTHREADINFO<T> >

...

MAP_THREADS(T) mapThreads;
```

Sorry it does not demonstrate the original example, but you get the drift.